# Python directory crawler to scan all kinds of files and search for keyword

Tags: python

I am trying to create a directory crawler to search for specific keywords in all files inside a folder and all its subfolders. This is what I have so far (in this case I am looking for keyword 'olofx'):

```
import os

rootDir = os.getcwd()

def scan_file(filename, dirname):
    print(os.path.join(dirname,filename))

    contains = False

    if("olofx" in filename):
        contains = True
    else:
        with open(os.path.join(dirname,filename)) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            for l in lines:
                #print(l)
                if("olofx" in l):
                    contains = True
                    break

    if contains:
        print("yes")

for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(rootDir):
    for fname in fileList:
        scan_file(fname, dirName)
```

Problem is when I reach one of my sample excel files, the characters seem to be unreadable.

here is some of the output for the excel file:

```
;���+͋�۳�L���P!�/��KdocProps/core.xml �(���_K�0���C�{�v�9Cہʞ

n(���v
      6H�ݾ�i���|Lι��sI���:��VJ'    �@1ͅ�h�^�s9O��VP�8�(//r���6`��r���7c�v ���
```

I have worked with openpyxl and I know I can use that to read excel files, but I want one script that reads all kinds of files: word, excel, pdf etc. Anyway to represent files' contents regardless of file types?

Thank you

Comment: what python version are you using?

Comment: `with open(os.path.join(dirname,filename), "rb") as f:` You have to read these files as bytecode.

Comment: using Python 2.7.15

Comment: with open(os.path.join(dirname,filename), "rb") as f:  -> added this, still getting the same output for excel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code assumes that the content of your files is available as plain text.

Unfortunately, for many file types this is not the case. Office documents (`.docx`, `.xslx`) are basically XML documents inside a ZIP archive. That means that the text content is saved in a compressed way, so when you parse the file bytes as plain text, the content is not recognisable.

You will need the necessary tools to interpret each of your file types correctly. There are libraries for this. One that I found is https://textract.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ but I have no experience with it.

Answer (score -3):

It seems, that Your script is saved with different encoding, as Your files, which are likely UTF-8 encoded.

Try to add at the very beginning of Your file the following line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

You may also check the following answer: [Character Encoding, XML, Excel, python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921091/character-encoding-xml-excel-python)

Comment: I added #!/usr/bin/env python #-*- coding: utf-8 -*- at the beginning of the file, still nothing, will check that answer now

Comment: This is not an encoding issue. Encoding problems assume that we have a plaintext document. Office documents are not plaintext documents, but compressed archives.

Comment: Changing the script's encoding will only impact the encoding of literal strings in the source code.

Comment: .docx / .xslx are not plain text files. It's not related to encoding.